# Who invented the ternary (elvis ?:) operator?

Tags: operators, wikipedia, history, ternary

I checked in wikipedia about the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) and   I couldn't find a **History** section or it's inventor. I googled a bit more and came up empty.

Do any of you guys know who invented it?

Comment: Ternary and elvis are two different things. The list of languages on the elvis op at least *claim* it's in GNU C & C++ first but ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ For ternary it explicitly states it's from CPL.

Comment: Could it be Christopher Strachey? When did it became the elvis?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is not a programming question.

Comment: In Wikipedia you can read something about this topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about the history of programming are off-topic.